# how to rotate/scroll picker with a flick in scrollview in iphone sdk 3.0?

Tags: iphone, scrollviewer

I have a pickerView in a scollView, which would rotate if i sweep across it in sdk 2.2.1 according to http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8284448

but when i changed the target to sdk 3.0, it is only responding to tapping and rotate 1 row at a time. but for many values that way is tiresome.

can anyone help me here to rotate the picker as it did in sdk 2.2.1 ??

Answer (score 0):

[Post edited -- sorry, didn't realize your picker view was inside a scroll view just now]

You can find the solution or your problem in the discussion here:
http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9630390

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-3/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008407-SW2 states the issue and its solution